# How to extract feature names from reduced dimension set?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pca, autoencoder

I am using PCA and/or Deep Autoencoders to reduce the dimensions of my set, but my question is instead of just having the reduced dimension of the set, is it possible or how is it possible to receive the feature names of these dimensions?

For example: 
As an autoencoder response, I am having the following result:

```
encoded_out[0:2]
out: array([[ 3.74947715,  0.        ,  3.22947764],
            [ 3.93903661,  0.17448257,  1.86618853]], dtype=float32)
```

But, I would like to know the column names (feature names) of these three columns.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean you want to know the feature names? There are no feature names, you just name them in your convenience!!

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR, The features of the encoder are a black box which you need to explore if you wish to interpret them. They have no immediate meaning or "column names".

Auto-encdoers transform your data from some high dimensional space into a bottleneck layer, often called a latent space, and back to the original input shape. This latent space is a compressed representation of the data, and for the latent representation to be effective, your network is trying to extract the most significant features of your data.

Unfortunately, its not easy (and often quite hard) to interpret the meaning of the latent space. You can try using visualization techniques to visualize your data, such as t-SNE that creates a 2D projection of the latent space and from there you need to need to research the underlying meaning of your representation.